# angular ui bootstrap popover not working

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

i am starting to learn to use angular's ui bootstrap library and trying to get a popover working. Am i missing something in my setup?

i've provided a plunker example. my requirement is to have a popover over cells in a table that gets refreshed by $interval every second.

http://plnkr.co/edit/hF3EDIRfKA1VOfSennZq?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>angular-test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("test", ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller("testCtrl", function($scope, $interval) {

        var stats = [{
                "name": "john",
                "stat1": 3,
                "stat2": 5
            }];

        var count = 0;
        $scope.getTestInfo = function() {
            $scope.count = count++;
            $scope.stats = stats;
        }

        $interval(function(){$scope.getTestInfo();}, 1000);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-init="count=0">
        <table id="table1" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>column1</th>
                <th>column2</th>
                <th>column3</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="bg-info">
            <tr ng-repeat="stat in stats">
                <td uib-popover="testcolumn1">{{stat.name}}</td>
                <td uib-popover="{{stat.stat1}}">{{stat.stat1 + count}}</td>
                <td uib-popover="testcolumn3">{{stat.stat2}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the metadata (`popover-trigger` etc.) for the popover modal. I forked your plunkr to demonstrate. http://plnkr.co/edit/d1eAf2NEAA9mCXmNN5LC?p=preview

Comment: thanks! that definitely fixed my plunker example and works exactly how i'd like it work. but when i tried it on my app, the popover seems to be "flashing" everytime the $interval is called. here is a stripped down version of my app. i've place it in the plunker and if you hover of the mistake cell, you'll see the popover disapears.. http://plnkr.co/edit/g68EEdC8Wq5eFPQG2ciG?p=preview

Comment: Your `var stats` at the top of the script is outside of the angular namespace. Assigning the array contained in that variable to `$scope` directly (which is what you should be doing anyway) fixes the problem. http://plnkr.co/edit/KDsE4GPEhwTpubEcq5jK?p=preview

Comment: in your example, did you change the plunker? are you able to provide an example?

Comment: I did, but i hurried and left some extraneous stuff. To summarize, your problem was assigning the retrieved array of agents to a variable outside of the angular namespace (which you did with `var stats`. Instead, you want to assign the agent array to a `$scope` variable. Here's a cleaned up plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/KDsE4GPEhwTpubEcq5jK?p=preview.